# First Two out of five images don't get onClick, but only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

Observe the following painfully simple construction:

```
<div id="home_thumbnails"> 
    <img onClick='loadFeature(0);' src='image_1.jpg'> 
    <img onClick='loadFeature(1);' src='image_2.jpg'> 
    <img onClick='loadFeature(2);' src='image_3.jpg'> 
    <img onClick='loadFeature(3);' src='image_4.jpg'> 
    <img onClick='loadFeature(4);' src='image_5.jpg'> 
</div>
```

In firefox, this does exactly as advertised.

In Chrome, however, loadFeature doesn't get called *for the first two images*. I have an `alert()` at the top of `function loadFeature()` that demonstrates that the function isn't even called by the first two. The remaining three, however, call it just great.

Any explanation for this would be MUCH appreciated

Comment: A small live test page would help. What's the smallest amount of code you need to replicate this?

Comment: The code looks like it should work to me.  Please provide us with a test page where this problem occurs as Rich indicated.  Thanks.

Comment: How complicated is your markup?  Could it be that there's an absolutely-positioned transparent `<div>` (or something like that) covering up the first two images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Here is a recreation of what could be happening](http://jsfiddle.net/yP94n/)**.

There's probably a transparent div or image covering up the first two images.

For example, take this innocuous looking code:

```
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadFeature(number)
    {
        alert(number);
    }
</script>
<div id="important"></div>
<div id="home_thumbnails">
    <img onClick='loadFeature(0);' src='image1.jpg'>
    <img onClick='loadFeature(1);' src='image2.jpg'>
    <img onClick='loadFeature(2);' src='image3.jpg'>
    <img onClick='loadFeature(3);' src='image4.jpg'>
    <img onClick='loadFeature(4);' src='image5.jpg'>
</div>​
</body></html>
```

Combine the above code with images of width `X` and height `Y` and the following CSS:

```
#important {
    width:2Xpx;
    height:Ypx;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0; }​
```

and your first two image are not clickable.

Comment: That's exactly what's going on. Thanks for the clarity of your example!

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this in Chrome, and it works without a hitch:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadFeature(number)
    {
        alert(number);
    }
</script>

<div id="home_thumbnails">
    <img onClick='loadFeature(0);' src='image_1.jpg'>
    <img onClick='loadFeature(1);' src='image_2.jpg'>
    <img onClick='loadFeature(2);' src='image_3.jpg'>
    <img onClick='loadFeature(3);' src='image_4.jpg'>
    <img onClick='loadFeature(4);' src='image_5.jpg'>
</div>
```

You might want to make sure that nothing might be removing or replacing your onClick events, or that no hidden/invisible elements are hiding/covering part of your div/images. If that's not the case, could you post some more of your code (such as your loadFeature function)?

Answer (score 2):

This might be odd, but check for any other elements overlapping with first two images.
Maybe you are actually clicking on that element, instead of your images, so the `onclick` event won't fire on `img` elements.